# BackboneJS MarionetteJS - waiting until collection has finished fetching

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I have a BackboneJS & MarionetteJS app

```
class MyApp extends Marionette.Application

app = new MyApp
app.addRegions
  tag_container    :"#tag_container"
  item_container   :"#item_container"

app.addInitializer( =>
  app.items = new ItemCollection()
  app.item_container.show(new ItemListView({collection:app.items}))
)
```

In my ItemCollection,

```
class ItemCollection extends Backbone.Collection
  model :ItemModel
  url   :"/get_items"

  initialize: =>
    @search()

  search: =>
    @reset()
    @fetch()
```

Above code displays the ItemListView immediately and adds the items as they are being fetched.

How can I wait until the collection has finished fetching THEN display the ItemListView in the "item_container"?

Comment: Consider moving your fetch outside of your collection initializer and into your controller / router.  Then the solution Robert proposed will be easier to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use a listener to know when the collection has finished his job. You can listen to `reset` if you're resetting it (not the default behavior as of Backbone 0.9.10) or `sync` (always done).
Or you can use the `success` callback.
[Source](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch)

A third solution would be to do a synchronous fetch:

```
@fetch async: false
```

Comment: +1 for binding the sync i.e collection.on("sync",this.myfunction.this)

Answer (score 1):

fetch returns a jquery promise.  so you can just do

```
collection.fetch().done(function() { 
 // create & show the view
});
```