# How to use a filter from a model in my route

Tags: backbone.js

If i have defined a filter in my collection like this:

```
filterByEveryday: function(){
    return this.models.filter(
      function(c) { 
        return c.Everyday == true; 
      })
   }
```

How can I use that filter in my route to select just the everyday breakfasts?

my route looks like this (currently fetching all the foods)

```
  products: function(type){
    console.log('product' + type );
    Breakfast.foods = new Breakfast.Collections.Foods()

    new Breakfast.Views.Foods({ collection: Breakfast.foods }); 
    Breakfast.foods.fetch();
    console.log(Breakfast.foods.filterByEveryday().length)
  },
```

There are a few problems here.
1.  Breakfast.foods.filterByEveryday().length returns 0.  Even if i change the test to true.  I guess I am using it wrong?
2.  There seems to be a lot of logic in the route, is this normal for backbone? seems like it should be in the view, but I'm not sure how to refactor it and have per route filters.
3.  trying to pass the filtered collection to the view like this:

```
collection: Breakfast.foods.filterByEveryday()
```

gives me

```
TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'bind'
```

So thats wrong too i suppose.

Comment: So, what is the problem here?

Comment: The problem is i don't really know how, or where to use my filter.

Comment: Are you just trying to filter your collection **after** fetching or do you just want to fetch only a part of your data?

Comment: fetching only part would be fine.  Its just a json file for the data store. I'm updating the question to better show all the things I'm confused about

Answer (score 3):

I'll answer both your first and third question. About the logic, I'd say do what you want ;) remember though that the way you're doing it, if someone navigate twice to the same route, you'll fetch your collection twice and so on...

So let's start. You may think you have a problem with your filter call. Wrong. Your problem comes from the line just before: `Breakfast.foods.fetch();`. AJAX calls are **asynchronous** by default. Some, by the time you call `filter`, your data hasn't come back from the server. Therefore, the 0 length (the collection itself has a 0 length). I invite you to look at [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055153) I've just answered to see what to do here.

Now, about the reason `collection: Breakfast.foods.filterByEveryday()` gives you an error. The problem doesn't essentially comes from Backbone. The problem is what you do with that in the object you created. `Breakfast.foods.filterByEveryday()` will return an **array**, not a collection. Therefore, when (I assume) you're doing a `this.collection.bind(...)` afterwards, you're trying to bind a listener to an **array**, which doesn't have the bind method. I'll let you find a solution among many to listen to the events of a sub-collection. Still, I'd like to insist on the use of [Events#listenTo](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) method (as of Backbone 0.9) which is (arguably, but from my point of view) better to bind listeners (it's easier to remove them and set the context).

As a final word, I'd say filter isn't useful the way you use it. [Collection#where](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where) and [Collection#findWhere](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-findWhere) are the methods to use in such case.

Comment: Thanks.  Good feedback.  "Where" also returns an array, so I'd still have issues trying to use it in the router to get the collection to be limited to "everday" items.  what is the normal backbone way to pass parameters to the data query for the view?

Comment: "*pass parameters to the data query for the view?*" you mean to the `fetch`?

Comment: the fetch is getting the data from a static json file.  so i'd rather pass it to the view so i can run the filter there, rather than the fetch - there isn't an api to query.

Comment: I don't know what's preventing you from fetching the data, and do your bindings in your view once the data is loaded. Could you be more specific about what part's a problem (edit your question to add the interesting part of your view maybe).